# Reading XML File in Loop

Tags: c#, mysql, xml, loops

I have just started learning C#,
but Im facing a situation.

Lets say, I have this XML file, which is being generated by an application at 1Hz refresh rate.
So I need C# to continuously parse this file, until a button is clicked to stop the action.

This is what i have right, a code that i picked up from few places

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("data.xml");
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/LiveData/Name");
int count = 1;
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
string Name = xn["Name"].InnerText;
string Value= xn["Value"].InnerText;
Console.WriteLine("Values: {0} {1}", Name, Value);
count = count + 1;
}
```

So this is done once, but now, what I want to do is, lets say, I have two buttons named, Start and Stop, once I start, the loop should continue on reading the file, since the file gets updated ever 1sec, and then when i click the Stop button the whole process should stop.

Also, I need to store this value in a database, so do you think inserting this in MySql every second would be a bad option?

Please help

Comment: Maybe you can avoid reading continuously that file by using a `FileSystemWatcher` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you want to read the file each second and not use `FileSystemWatcher` as remio suggested, you should use a timer. There are several timers available in .Net. Which one you should choose depends on what kind of application you have (Winforms or WPF).

Inserting the values into the database every second shouldn't be a problem. But you should be prepared on dealing with that amount of data, it will go into gigabytes if you do this for several months continuously.